# What does "One shot, send them here" mean?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man, spider-man-no-way-home

In a cave scene from *Spider Man No Way Home* (2021), Dr Strange gives a hand brace to Peter Parker:

> Dr Strange: **One shot, send them here**, move on. You're welcome. Get to
> work.
>
> Peter Parker: Sir?
>
> Dr Strange: Now what?
>
> Peter Parker: I know this is my mess, and I swear to you I'll fix it,
> but I'm gonna need help.

What does "One shot, send them here" mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This, I believe, takes place after Spider-Man botches Dr. Strange's memory spell, causing villains from across the multiverse - Green Goblin, Doctor Octopus, Sandman, Lizard, and Electro - to be pulled into the MCU. The hand brace Dr. Strange gives Spider-Man contains some sort of spell that, when fired at those villains, will teleport them into holding cells in the Sanctum Sanctorum, ready for Strange to send them back to their original universes.

"Send them here" is therefore self-explanatory, while "one shot" is a reminder for Peter to be as accurate as possible while doing so, because *anything* he hits will be transported into the cells. (This point is hammered home during the Electro fight when he misses and hits a tree, which gets transported into one of the cells.)